# How do I best detect an ASP.NET expired session?

Tags: asp.net, http, session

I need to detect when a session has expired in my Visuial Basic web application.  This is what I'm using...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If CurrentSession.IsNew AndAlso (Not Page.Request.Headers("Cookie") Is Nothing) AndAlso (Page.Request.Headers("Cookie").IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0) Then
        Response.Redirect("TimeOut.aspx")
    End If

    ...do something...

End Sub
```

**Note:** `CurrentSession.IsNew` returns `HttpContext.Current.Session.IsNewSession`

This seems to work well for *Internet Explorer*, but seems to fail with *Firefox*.

Comment: Can you work with the Session_End function in Global.asax? [http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5771721.html](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5771721.html)

Comment: I'm only currently using the Application_Error event in the global.asax file. Perhaps my session handling belongs there as well. But, how do I use that on the requested page load?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following

```
If Session("whatever") IsNot Nothing Then
```